# Tippy.js only works after first page refresh on Angular project

Tags: angular, tippyjs

I have installed tippy.js on my angular project, which is a tooltip library (https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/), but it only works after refreshing the page for the first time.

I've installed it through **npm install tippy.js** command and imported it into **angular.json** file as follows:

```
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
          "./node_modules/tippy.js/umd/index.all.min.js"
        ],
```

The html element responsible for calling it is written like so:

```html
 <span data-tippy="Tooltip" class="layout-semester theme-semester"><strong>2019</strong>-1sem</span>
```

I think the library is being loaded before the page is fully constructed, but have no idea on how to do it on an Angular project...

Comment: when exactly are you initiating a `tippy('selector')`  ?

Comment: Actually I'm not. When I try and do it, the tooltip stops working even after refreshing... the way I tried was to import another js file into scripts like so             "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/tippy.js/umd/index.all.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/tippy.js"
            ], the tippy.js file had only the following line: tippy('#tippy') and when I did it, I also changed data-tippy="Tooltip" to data-tippy-content="Tooltip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used tippy, but reading their [docs](http://when%20exactly%20are%20you%20initiating%20a%20%60tippy('selector')%60%20%20?%20I%20haven't%20used%20tippy,%20but%20reading%20their%20docs,%20it%20looks%20like%20you%20need%20to%20run%20a%20%60tippy(%3Cselector%3E)%60%20for%20it%20to%20run%20through%20selectors%20and%20%22activate%22%20dom%20change,%20that%20you%20call,%20a%20tool%20tip.), it looks like you need to run a `tippy(<selector>)` for it to run through selected elements and "activate" the DOM change, which you call, a tool tip.

in Angular, i'd guess it would work something like:

```
import tippy from 'tippy.js'

ngAfterViewInit() {
    tippy('span');
}
```

EDIT: [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzn8ur?file=src/app/app.component.ts), seems to work as expected.